# jQuery fade in ajax loaded div isn't smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When running the following locally, the fade in is very smooth, but on a remote server the content loaded into the target div appears, is instantly hidden, and then fades back in again.

**Why does this happen and how do I fix it?**

My jQuery (inside the document.ready stuff) looks like this:

```
$(".dataclick").click(function()
{
    $('.clicktarget').hide().load($(this).attr("href")).fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
        <ul>
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/lameness.html">Lameness Investigations</a></li>
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/xrays.html">Xrays &amp; Ultrasonography</a></li>                               
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/shockwave.html">Shockwave Therapy</a></li>
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/prepurchase.html">Pre-Purchase Examinations</a></li>
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/vettings.html">Vettings</a></li>                               
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/reproduction.html">AI &amp; Full Reproductive Service</a></li>
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/endoscopy.html">Endoscopy</a></li>
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/acupuncture.html">Acupuncture</a></li>
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/dentistry.html">Full Dentistry Service</a></li>
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/castration.html">Castrations</a></li>                              
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/gastroscopy.html">Gastroscopy</a></li>
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/ridingschool.html">Riding School Inspection</a></li>
            <li><a class="dataclick" href="/data/24hremergency.html">24hr Emergency Service</a></li>                                
        </ul>

        <p>For more information on each service please click the relevant title/link.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="clicktarget">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want the fading to start before the content has loaded, so you should pass a callback to `.load()`:

```
$(".dataclick").click(function() {
    $('.clicktarget').hide().load($(this).attr("href"), function(){
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Knew it was something like that!